# App crashes when resizing window with mapview in Xcode 12

Tags: xcode, macos, mkmapview, lldb, nswindow

My single view native macOS app crashes with lldb error.

It crashes with the message *** -[MTLDebugTexture removeUsedRenderTarget: slices:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x-------.

The error thread reads EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (CODE=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)

I haven't written any code. just the storyboard and auto layout

Comment: Did you manage to find a fix for this?